# lost the session data after redirecting to stripe

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am creating a food ordering system in spring MVC with stripe payment integration. when I am trying to get the attribute from session inside the webhook controller which I had set in it previously I am getting null. why?

and most importantly how to solve it?

**edit:**

This is my payment-intent controller which is called by a client.js file, now here I set the items in session and this controller returns the client secret id generated by the stripe to the client.js , now client.js call the stripe and makes a successful payment and on payment confirmation stripe sends me a webhook on my localhost endpoint with charge.succeeded event. Now to handle that event I need session attributes but I am unable to get them from the session as it returns null.

**Payment-Intent Controller**

```java
@RestController public class PaymentController {
    @PostMapping("/create-payment-intent")
    public CreatePaymentResponse createPaymentIntent(@RequestBody CreatePayment createPayment, 
    HttpServletRequest req)
        throws StripeException {

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonItem[] jsonItems = createPayment.getItems();
    for (JsonItem jsonItem : jsonItems) {
        items.add(jsonItem.getItemid());
    }

    session.setAttribute("pnames", items);

    Float amount = Float.parseFloat(createPayment.getAmount());
    System.out.println(amount.longValue() * 100l);
    PaymentIntentCreateParams createParams = new PaymentIntentCreateParams.Builder()
            .setCurrency("INR")
            .setAmount(amount.longValue() * 100L)
            .setDescription("product's amount")
            .build();

    PaymentIntent intent = PaymentIntent.create(createParams);
    CreatePaymentResponse paymentResponse = new CreatePaymentResponse(intent.getClientSecret());
    return paymentResponse;
}
}
```

**This is my Webhook Controller**

```java
    @RestController
    public class StripeWebhookController {

    @Autowired
    private FoodhubServiceImpl service;
    
    @Autowired
    private Payment payment;
    
    private String endpointSecret="some endpoint secret";
    
    
    @PostMapping("/foodhub/endpoint")
    public String handleStripeEvents(@RequestBody String payload, @RequestHeader("Stripe-Signature") String sigHeader,HttpServletRequest req) {
        
                HttpSession session = req.getSession();
                
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("pnames");//null
                System.out.println(arr.get(0));//null pointer exception
                
                if(sigHeader == null) {
                    return "";
                }
                
                Event event; 
      
                try {
                    event = Webhook.constructEvent(
                        payload, sigHeader, endpointSecret
                    );
                } catch (SignatureVerificationException e) {
                    // Invalid signature
                    System.out.println("Webhook error while validating signature.");
                    System.out.println(e);
                    return "";
                }
                
            // Deserialize the nested object inside the event
            EventDataObjectDeserializer dataObjectDeserializer = event.getDataObjectDeserializer();
            StripeObject stripeObject = null;
            if (dataObjectDeserializer.getObject().isPresent()) {
                stripeObject = dataObjectDeserializer.getObject().get();
            } else {
                // Deserialization failed, probably due to an API version mismatch.
                // Refer to the Javadoc documentation on `EventDataObjectDeserializer` for
                // instructions on how to handle this case, or return an error here.
            }
            // Handle the event
            switch (event.getType()) {
                case "payment_intent.succeeded":
                    PaymentIntent paymentIntent = (PaymentIntent) stripeObject;
                    System.out.println("Payment succeeded for   "+paymentIntent.getAmount());
                    System.out.println("payload is : "+payload);
                    handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
                    // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unhandled event type: " + event.getType());
                    break;
            }
            return "200";
    }


    private void handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(PaymentIntent paymentIntent) {
        
        //do some stuff here    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the sequence of URLs being loaded, from where. For instance, if the webhook controller is being called _from_ Stripe, not as a browser _redirect_, it won't ever have access to the user's session.

Comment: Please add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: @dbreaux my webhook controller is being called from stripe not as a bowser redirect so isn't there any way of getting the same session data? please guide me .

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks are delivered as completely separate [POST requests](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#key-considerations) directly from Stripe's [webhook delivery servers](https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications) when events are generated. Your customer is not redirected to this in any way, and the request will not include anything other than the event object.

You cannot get your session data like you're trying to do from a webhook event.

Instead, you can set `metadata` when creating the Payment Intent ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-metadata)), and that `metadata` will be included in any Payment Intent webhook events.